# Is there a limit to the number of low-quality posts that I can flag?

Tags: support, flagging, low-quality-posts, rate-limiting

I've recently got the privilege of recommending deletion and recommending closing low-quality posts and I've been quite active trying to do my bit giving feedback but the dialog box that shows up on doing so that asks specifying reasons for deletion or closing seems to indicate $7$ flags remaining.

So my question basically is, is there a limit to the number of posts we can actually flag as being low-quality. If so? Why is that and does that number in our account get renewed sometime later maybe weekly or monthly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit *per day.* You get at least 10 and up to 100 flags per day. The precise number depends on your points and on your flag record.

For details see this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/

Almost all actions on SE are limited in some way. For all the details see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)